# DCOS/Mesos doesn't unreserve resources on framework delete

Tags: mesos, dcos

Hi after delete of a framework (e.g. Cassandra or Kafka) the resources for them are still reserved. This makes me impossible to install another framework because of lack of free resources.

Using this to check:

```
    curl master.mesos/mesos/slaves
    .... 
      "reserved_resources": {
      "cassandra-role": {
        "disk": 10240.0,
        "mem": 5376.0,
        "gpus": 0.0,
        "cpus": 1.5,
        "ports": "[7000-7001, 7199-7199, 9001-9001, 9042-9042, 9160-9160]"
      }
    },
    "unreserved_resources": {
      "disk": 32503.0,
      "mem": 567.0,
      "gpus": 0.0,
      "cpus": 0.5,
      "ports": "[1025-2180, 2182-3887, 3889-5049, 5052-6999, 7002-7198, 7200-8079, 8082-8180, 8182-9000, 9002-9041, 9043-9159, 9161-32000]"
    }
```

How do I can free these resources and is it normal that Mesos doesn't unreserve them on a framework deletion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Janitor as described in https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/usage/managing-services/uninstall/

The deletion of a framework and the unreservation of resources are two different things.